# Convert lon/lat collection to geom/linestring

Tags: postgresql, gis, postgis

I have a column in postgis like:

```
[{"lang":-122.39726983952495,"lat":37.789519907547806},{"lang":-122.39703479547161,"lat":37.78933265166566}]
```

I need to draw the line on OpenLayers Map by converting this column to geometry.

Comment: It is not quite clear what your value is: Is it a JSON object or a text or a geometry. Furthermore I think it should be "long" instead of "lang" ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[step-by-step demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=9da13aa56ffc226dc0ff2350a31a2303) (From JSON to line as geometry)

```
SELECT
    st_makeline(                              -- 5
        array_agg(point.point)                -- 4
    )
FROM
    my_table,
    json_array_elements(my_points) AS elems,  -- 1
    st_makepoint(                             -- 3
        (elems ->> 'lang')::numeric,          -- 2
        (elems ->> 'lat')::numeric
    ) AS point
```

1. Creates one row for each array element
2. Getting the numeric values from the json object
3. Create point geometries for every row
4. Aggregate all point geometries into one geometry array
5. Create line geomatries out of geometry array

Comment: Hi,  can you please give me some more favour.
I'm trying to add the resultant "geometry" of each row into the new column.
what will be my end-query. Thanks

Comment: @MuhammadZahid https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=25ec561915c2917d60af3a70632c5f76